# Problem of Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct!

Tags: debian, locale

When I always try to install new package I get this message:

```
Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct!
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_GB:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

My OS is Debian Jessie 8.3 (Mate) using English with French keyboard.
When I type locale, I get this:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Debian ships locales in source form. They need to be compiled explicitly. The reason for this is that compiled locales use a lot more disk space, but most people only use a few of them.

Run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root, select the locales you want in the list (with your settings, you need `en_GB` and `en_US.UTF-8` — I recommend selecting `en_US` and `en_GB.UTF-8` as well) then press `<OK>`.

Alternatively, edit `/etc/locale.gen`, uncomment the lines for the locales you want, and run `locale-gen` as root.

(Note: on Ubuntu, this works differently: run `locale-gen` with the locales you want to generate as arguments, e.g. `sudo locale-gen en_GB en_US en_GB.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8`.)

Alternatively, Debian now has a package `locales-all` which you can install instead of `locales`. It has all the locales pre-generated. The downside is that they use up more disk space (112MB vs 16MB).

Comment: It worked, but only after I logged out and then logged in again.

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: editing `/etc/locale.gen` does't did the job for me (did logout/login), but `locale-gen` solved my `tmux: need UTF-8 locale (LC_CTYPE)` problem on `Debian 4.9.82`

Comment: @eapo As I state in my answer, you need to edit `/etc/locale.gen` **and** then run `locale-gen`.

Comment: I missed the bit about enabling `en_US.UTF-8` as well and your own locale. I found out the hard way then circled back here to make my own answer before realising it was here all along.

Comment: Since I mixed, a Spanish clock; with American English, system language; Japanese keyboard, I had to install all these to work properly in Debian 9.7(last version) because either it don't!

Comment: I had KDM desktop that had an unusual locale set (de_EN), and that was interfering with the LANG and LC_* settings. So I changed it to match the locale that I wanted, and then did `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`. Then it worked fine.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 38):

The top-rated solution didn't help in my case, so I used this one:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

After that, I logged out and logged in and error was missing.

Comment: Using LC_ALL is strongly discouraged as it overrides everything. Please use it only when testing and never set it in a startup file. as per: https://wiki.debian.org/Locale

Answer (score 15):

If you're having this issue on a raspberry pi (or other?) and you're getting the error when you ssh to the pi there are 2 other solutions

One is edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the pi and comment out the line

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

for example `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

After which you should restart the ssh server

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

The other is on your client machine (**not the pi**) edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (different path from above) and comment out the line

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Comment: Both of these are uncommented for me but problem still arises. (RPi3, macOS10.14)

Comment: Commented *out* the line now. Don't really have the opportunity to test but sounds more logical this way... Thanks.

Comment: Works on `raspberry pi` with `Debian 10`. What is the idea? Throwing away `locale settings` in a ssh session that is sent from the client host.

Answer (score 14):

These commands saved my life

```
# echo "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
# echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
# echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.conf
# locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the package `locales` (or `locales-all` or the en_GB locale, depending on the Debian version you have).

A workaround not to have such errors: set `LANG=C` to root, so that it will use *no* locales.