# Install libc-bin 2.36 on Debian 11

Tags: debian, glibc

I need to upgrade `libc-bin` from the current stable version to 2.36 on Debian 11. I have tried to do so by downloading the .deb package from `http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-bin_2.36-8_amd64.deb`, however when I install it with `dpkg --install package.deb`, I am then unable to use `apt install` because it asks me to run `apt --fix-broken install` and when I do so, it breaks some basic packages and tells me `dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable`. After that, I cannot install anything else neither via a`pt install` nor via `dpkg --install package.deb`.

How can I then install `libc-bin 2.36` without breaking `apt` and without switching to the unstable channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a similar situation to the problem in [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/741911/86440): you need to keep all libc-related packages at the same version.

To upgrade to libc 2.36, you need to install at least the `libc-bin`, `libc6`, and `locales` 2.36 packages. Note that in doing so you will have started the upgrade towards Debian 12 and you should plan on finishing it soon after it’s released. It’s possible that some of your other installed packages will be broken by the upgrade and will have to be updated to versions in Debian testing. I highly recommend reconsidering the upgrade, unless you want to end up helping the Debian project test its upcoming release.